# how do I retrieve multiple rows of a MYSQL table using java

Tags: java, mysql, jtable, defaulttablemodel, data-retrieval

I am developing a java application in which I have a `jInternalFrame` Form called `LCI` in which I have two `jTextFields` called `DATE`and `SUB_ID_`.I have db connection with the database called `FINAL_POST` in which I have the table called `LCI`.

What I need to get done is compare above two user inputs with the columns called `L_DATE` and `SUB_ID` respectively each record of the SQL table and retrieve matching records on to a `jTable` called `tb1`.

Suppose if there are two records that tally with the `DATE` input and the `SUB_ID_`input and one record is entered at 10.12 a.m. in the morning and the other one is entered at 1.15 p.m. on same date,in such cases only the first record is been retrieved at the moment.

In other words even though there are several records tally with the `DATE` and `SUB_ID_`exist,only the very first record is being retrieved.

Below is my code for the relevant `jButton`called Load_To_Table.[`DATE` , `SUB_ID_`, `Load_To_Table` and `tb1`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWafN.png)

```
private void Load_To_TableActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        try{

            Statement s = DB.getConnection().createStatement();
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            ResultSet rs,rs1,rs2,rs3,rs4,rs5,rs6,rs7;
            rs=j.getData("select E_ID from User where E_ID='"+user+"'");
            rs1=j.getData("select * from employee where E_ID= '"+user+"'");
            rs2=j.getData("select * from SUBJECT where SUB_ID= '"+SUB_ID_.getText()+"'");
            rs3=j.getData("select * from LCI");
            if((((rs.next()==true)&&(rs1.next()==true))&&(rs2.next()==true))&&(rs3.next()==true))
            {
                if((rs.getString(1).equals(rs2.getString(4)))&&(rs2.getString(4).equals(rs3.getString(5))))
        {
                 rs4=j.getData("select * from LCI where SUB_ID='"+SUB_ID_.getText()+"'");

                    if((rs4.next()==true))
                    {
                       try
                       {                      
                            rs5=j.getData("select count(L_DATE)from LCI where L_DATE='"+DATE.getText()+"'");

                            if(rs5.next())
                            {
                                int count=rs5.getInt(1);
                                System.out.println(rs5.getInt(1));

                                DefaultTableModel dtm=(DefaultTableModel)tb1.getModel();
                                Vector v=new Vector();
                                Vector v1=new Vector(); 
                                Vector v2=new Vector(); 

                                for(int i=0;i<=count;i++)
                                {
                                    rs6=j.getData("select * from LCI where L_DATE='"+DATE.getText()+"'");

                                    if(rs6.next()==true)
                                    {
                                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Done");                        
                                        v.addElement(rs6.getString(1));
                                        dtm.addColumn(v);
                                        v1.addElement(rs6.getString(3));
                                        dtm.addColumn(v1);
                                        v2.addElement(rs6.getString(10));
                                        dtm.addColumn(v2);
                                     s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM   LCI WHERE  L_ID IN(SELECT (L_ID + 1)FROM   LCI  WHERE  L_DATE = '"+DATE.getText()+"'");
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please try another date");
                                    }           
                                }                      
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                System.out.println("not ok");
                            }
                        }                        

                        catch(Exception ex)
                        {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Your Employee Identity is not valid.Please contact the admin");
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "comparision failed");
                }
            }
           else{
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Failed to connect with database.Please re-check your Employee Identity Nuumber and Try again.");
           }
        }
        catch(Exception  ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
// TODO add your handling code here:
    }
```

[`LCI` table description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gx3Ar.png)

[`LCI` table containing two data items matching with both of the user inputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clYSN.png)

[Out put containg only one record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prUDW.png)

I am puzzled here how to get retrieved all the matching records onto `tb1`.

How to get this done?

Or if any one can tell me how to command the programme to read/go to next line/record of the db table and check whether that record is matching with both of the user inputs, please do not hesitate. :)

I am using Netbeans 8.0.2 for GUI creation and "MYSQL Query Browser" for the database.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to redesign your code,too many `if` check and the variable name and code format are also very bad!

Comment: Consider using any ORM framework that interacts with your database. You don't have to struggle a lot when you receive a full fledged object from your database (ORM)

Comment: @lucumt, I am new to this. would you mind telling me how should I amend the code please?

Comment: @Shyam, I have no idea about how to use an Object-relational Mapper Software. I think I have more home work to do on it. :) Thanks to you, I learnt something today that is completely new to me.As an start can you please suggest which will be compatible with what I have already done here? Because I am running out of time to finish this project. :(

Comment: Yes, ORM is just a middle man that sits in between your application and database. Also you have mixed up your app logic with the database logic. Ideally, they shouldn't be mixed.

Comment: @Shyam , Thank you. I'll look into that.1)  Hence I am a novice to this field, can you please suggest something that is compatible with what I have done above. 2) So, how can I put the db logic things in action?